# shell: What is the purpose of ${var:-} when var is unset or null?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In my [Linux Mint 17.2 `/etc/bash.bashrc`](https://gist.github.com/cfe6dd30155bf378cfe90a7a2cd7f816) I see the following:

```
# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi
```

This is the first reference to the token `debian_chroot`.

Why does this code use `${debian_chroot:-}` instead of just `$debian_chroot`?

Bash's [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) says:

> ${parameter:-word}
>
> If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

Here, "word" is null, so why bother substituting null for null?

Comment: It probably protects you from an error  the shell is invoked with `-u` or executes [`set -u`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) — that causes a complaint when you use an undefined variable.  • _`-u`_  _Treat unset variables and parameters other than the special parameters ‘@’ or ‘*’ as an error when performing parameter expansion. An error message will be written to the standard error, and a non-interactive shell will exit._

Comment: Make this an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: In a very similar context, I see, e.g. `if [ "${PS1-}" `. What's happening here with this parameter-expansion-looking thingy? It looks like it's slightly different but at the same time so close that I didn't want to post a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax `${debian_chroot:-}` prevents the shell from exiting if it is running with `set -u` (crash when using undefined variables) and `debian_chroot` is unset at that point.

You *don't* want a normal interactive shell to have `set -u` (it would crash too easily), but it can be very useful in scripts.

To see this:

```
bash -c 'set -u; [ -z $a ]; echo ok'          # error
bash -c 'set -u; a=; [ -z $a ]; echo ok'      # ok
bash -c 'set -u; [ -z ${a:-} ]; echo ok'      # ok
bash -c 'set -u; a=; [ -z ${a:-} ]; echo ok'  # ok
```

Comment: The Bash manual says that `/etc/bash.bashrc` will only ever be automatically sourced by interactive shells, which leads me to believe this particular use of `${debian_chroot:-}` vs `$debian_chroot` is not necessary.

Comment: Note that you can also set a default in case the variable `a` is not defined: `${a:-default_value}`. See e.g. [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_03.html).

Answer (score 2):

The use of the `"${variable:-}"` notation protects the script from an error if the shell is somehow invoked with `-u` or executes [`set -u`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) — that causes a complaint when you use an undefined variable.

> `-u` Treat unset variables and parameters other than the special parameters ‘@’ or ‘*’ as an error when performing parameter expansion. An error message will be written to the standard error, and a non-interactive shell will exit.

Comment: Thanks for making this an answer - I have to run with @Matei's new post as the accepted answer though. +1

Answer (score -1):

The purpose is to set a default value so that certain constructs in bash would not break.For example

Suppose `var` is unset, then :

```
if [ $var = "" ] #breaks => bash: [: =: unary operator expected
```

but

```
 if [ "${var:-}" = "" ] # works fine
```

***In case of***

```
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] # z checks if a SET variable is empty.
```

***though***, it doesn't make a difference and should work with just `"${debian_chroot}"` provided the `-u` bash option is not set.

[[ bash reference ]](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html) says :

> -u(nounset)   Attempt to use undefined variable outputs error message, and forces an exit

Below script

```
#!/bin/bash -u
# note variable 'var' is unset
# Try the script as is and uncommenting the below line
#declare var=
if [ -z "${var}" ]
then
 echo "var is empty"
fi
# "${var:-}" would work even if the 'var' is not 'declare'd.
```

would give you better idea.

Comment: Tried it; worked fine. It'll only be a problem if `-u` is set, but that's not the default.

Comment: Both bash and dash handle this without problems if you remove `:-`

Comment: @GordonDavisson : In fact I pick the wrong example. thanks for hint on `-u`. Kinda forgot such a bash option exists ;) Pls see the update